# Conditional grouping in pandas and transpose

Tags: dataframe, pandas-groupby

With an input dataframe framed out of a given CSV, I need to transpose the data based on certain conditions. The groupby should be applied based on Key value.

For any value in the same 'Key' group, if the 'Type' is "T", these values should be written on "T" columns labelled as T1, T2, T3...and so on.

For any value in the same 'Key' group, if the 'Type' is "P" and 'Code' ends with "00" these values should be written on "U" columns labelled as U1, U2, U3...and so on.

For any value in the same 'Key' group, if the 'Type' is "P" and 'Code' doesn't end with "00" these values should be written on "P" columns labelled as P1, P2, P3...and so on.

There might be n number of values of type T & P for any Key value and the output columns for T & P should be updated accordingly

Input Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2'],
                   'Value': ['T101', 'T102', 'P101', 'P102', 'P103', 'T201', 'T202', 'P201', 'P202', 'P203'],
                   'Type': ['T', 'T', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'T', 'T', 'P', 'P', 'P'],
                   'Code': ['0', '0', 'ABC00', 'TWY01', 'JTH02', '0', '0', 'OUJ00', 'LKE00', 'WDF45']
                   })
```

[image]

Expected Dataframe:

[image]

Can anyone suggest an effective solution for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2'],
                   'Value': ['T101', 'T102', 'P101', 'P102', 'P103', 'T201', 'T202', 'P201', 'P202', 'P203'],
                   'Type': ['T', 'T', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'T', 'T', 'P', 'P', 'P'],
                   'Code': ['0', '0', 'ABC00', 'TWY01', 'JTH02', '0', '0', 'OUJ00', 'LKE00', 'WDF45']
                   })

# Set up the U label
df.loc[(df['Code'].apply(lambda x: x.endswith('00'))) & (df['Type'] == 'P'), 'Type'] = 'U'
# Type indexing by key by type
df = df.join(df.groupby(['Key','Type']).cumcount().rename('Tcount').to_frame() + 1)
df['Type'] = df['Type'] + df['Tcount'].astype('str')
# Pivot the table
pv =df.loc[:,['Key','Type','Value']].pivot(index='Key', columns='Type', values='Value')

>>>pv
Type    P1    P2    T1    T2    U1    U2
Key
1     P102  P103  T101  T102  P101   NaN
2     P203   NaN  T201  T202  P201  P202

cdf = df.loc[df['Code'] != '0', ['Key', 'Code']].groupby('Key')['Code'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))

>>>cdf
Key
1    ABC00,TWY01,JTH02
2    OUJ00,LKE00,WDF45
Name: Code, dtype: object

>>>pv.join(cdf)
       P1    P2    T1    T2    U1    U2               Code
Key                                                       
1    P102  P103  T101  T102  P101  None  ABC00,TWY01,JTH02
2    P203  None  T201  T202  P201  P202  OUJ00,LKE00,WDF45
```

Comment: @kerwie- This works as expected. How do I include the column code to the output df?

Comment: @Osceria How do you want to join it to the output?

Comment: Add the label Code to o/p df and concatenate all the codes associated with its Key value

Comment: @Osceria I'm afraid you need to come up with a sample. I don't quite follow the part on _o/p df_

Comment: updated the actual question with the expected dataframe